# Comparing dates within LINQ gives error - Method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to pull out the `HourRegistrations` where

```
HourRegistration.Date == //withint the last 3 months
```

I'm trying like this (found this solution on the web, but it doesn't seem to work)

```
var dbHourRegs = db.HourRegistration
        .Where(x => DateTime.Compare(x.Date, DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3)) >= 0)
        .ToList();
```

But as the title says, I keep getting this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddMonths(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How shall one proceed? Or rather, how do I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mehtod DateTime.Compare is C# method that can not be translated into sql query. Also `DateTime.Now.AddMonths` will also generate error due to same reason

You can do this instead

```
DateTime YourDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
var dbHourRegs = db.HourRegistration
        .Where(x => x.Date >= YourDate)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: This works, and this was actually a duplicate. I apologize but thanks for the support.

Comment: Yes, many similar questions are answered on this platform

Comment: the condition should be `x.Date >= YourDate` ,not `testDate >= x.Date` (`testDate` is not defined while `YourDate` is what defined).

Comment: The original code can be re-written to this `DateTime.Compare(x.Date, YourDate) >= 0`, so isn't that the condition should be `x.Date >= YourDate`? Or I understand the `Compare` method wrong?

Comment: Yes, you must not be hopeless @Hopeless.